# document.ready and on load function in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I study in jquery that when only html load it fire **document.ready** function and when all images or everything load it fire **onload** function.Same I need to find in angular could you please tell what first function fire and when html is load and what function fire when everything is load in angularjs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say that you have a div to which you want to attach on load function

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
```

From MainCtrl you can listen the event

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
```

});

You can listen in your controllers defined in routes like myController and myRouteController for $viewContentLoaded event, $viewContentLoaded is emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded and should provide similar functionality as the document.ready when routing in angularjs

Comment: viewContentLoaded is instead of onload i think .what about onready ?